# What are the different between "Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis" and "System.Speech.Synthesis"?

Tags: .net, windows, speech-synthesis

I'm trying t o determined which of the two APIs have more features to do text-to-speech in a pro application developed in C#.

OS is not an issues here, just how of the two namespaces offer more features, quality voices and stability.

Have any body master both tech and could tell me about the different in those two namespaces? Is one of them a super-set of the another in terms of features?

**EDIT:**

Behind of those two namespaces is the same *speech synthesis engine*?

My web app will do all the text-to-speech stuff at server side.

Comment: They have nothing in common, you use one in a Store or Phone app, the other in a desktop app.  Sounds like they are similar, but that's just the way a Ferrari and a bicycle are similar.  They both move you around but do so in *very* different ways.

Comment: What if my app is a web app that run on 2012 R2? [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechsynthesis.aspx) I read that *Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis* is 2012 R2 compatible. Still reading your comment I have doubts now if *Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis* is just a client library that depend of a server service or not. Is that correct?

Comment: Then you'll have to write Javascript.  Doesn't have anything to do with .NET of course, also rather low odds that the user will run his browser on 2012R2.  Kinda important that you keep on eye on where your code will run, it of course matters a great deal.  Nobody cares much about a web server that talks to nobody in a locked server room.  But yes, 2012R2 is capable of running Store apps.

Comment: @HansPassant Seem to me that I dont explained myself well. My app will be a web app and will do the text-to-speech stuff in the server side, that is why for me is not a big deal in which OS my app will run at. My questions basically is what of those two namespaces have more features to do text-to-speech and which of them can offer more regards quality in the voices and stability. If I end with a 2008 or 2012 server is not a big deal, the only thing that is important is how powerful each namespaces are.

Comment: A web server does *not* run a Store or Phone app, it runs an ASP.NET app.  So there's no point whatsoever in looking at System.Windows.SpeechSynthesis, that namespace is not available.  Very easy to find out for yourself simply by trying it btw.

Comment: But an ASP.NET app cant communicate with a Store app running in the same server (e.g. 2012)? as a way to gateway the text-to-speech processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis is part of the Windows Runtime and supports only Windows Store apps. It cannot be called from your server app and so won't serve your purpose.

System.Speech.SpeechSynthesis should work for you. You can call it on the server to generate a sound file via [SetOutputToWaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586883(v=vs.110).aspx) You can then expose the generated wave file \
from the server.

Barring that they target different environments, the end results would be similar.