# Windows 10 - System.Speech.Synthesis cannot get Mobile version of voice

Tags: c#, winforms, text-to-speech

In my Windows 10's Language, I have installed 2 version of English Language:

- US
- United Kingdom

Therefore, in [Settings] > [Time & language] > [Speech]

Under the section [Text-to-Speech], I can see the following options:

- Microsoft David Mobile
- Microsoft George Mobile
- Microsoft Susan Mobile
- Microsoft Hazel Mobile
- Microsoft Zira Mobile
- Microsoft Mark Mobile

but, in C# WinForm, by using the following code:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
ss.GetInstalledVoices();
```

I can only get:

- Microsoft David Desktop
- Microsoft Hazel Desktop
- Microsoft Zira Desktop

I missed Susan, George and Mark.

How can I get Susan, George and Mark voice version in C# WinForm?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @bslein No I haven't

Comment: You can only access the Windows 10 Voices from the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis Namespace which belongs to the WinRT Framework...

Comment: @bslein thanks dude :)

Comment: @bslein do you want to post it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only access the Windows 10 Voices from the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis Namespace which belongs to the WinRT Framework. So you cant use them in WPF or WinForms.

see:  [What are the different between "Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis" and "System.Speech.Synthesis"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710852/what-are-the-different-between-windows-media-speechsynthesis-and-system-speec/26355164#26355164)