# Using Microsoft Hazel Voice in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, text-to-speech

So I developed a UWP app with the TTS functionality as defined in the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis namespace, and it works great with the default voices (Mark, Zira and David) but I am unable to switch to the UK voices (Hazel, Susan and George) that I downloaded despite seeing them in the SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices List.

Now the weird thing is that I can hear sample speech from the UK voices in the Control Panel Settings, just not in the UWP app. The only thing I can think of is that they are not "Microsoft Signed" Voices, but I am unable to find anything indicating what are and are not Microsoft Signed Voices. Has anybody run into this problem before?

Comment: Do you download the UK voices in the Settings? If not, please try to open the Settings, chose Region & language, click Add a language, chose English(United Kindom), select Options and click  Download button under Speech.

Comment: Please fully read the question. I have the UK voices available in the Control Panel (Settings), so I definitely downloaded them.

Comment: I encountered this from search and it seems to be the reason from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44024919/999198